# MySQL - Trigger on Insert HOUR('time')

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a field 'timeduration'. Currently when I select the 'timeduration' value I'm doing  HOUR('timeduration') to get the time in hours. I would like to do this calculation when inserting the data into the table, so putting the hour value into it's own column.

```
|  date    |  timeduration  |  hour
  12-12-14    01:00:00         1
```

I've looked into triggers but not sure how to about this, or os there an easier way I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger would do it. And that's the only way to get MySQL to automatically populate the `hour` column on the row based on the value assigned to the `timeduration` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger would do it. And that's the only way to get MySQL to automatically populate the value in the `hour` column, based on the value assigned to the `timeduration` column.

Here's an example a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bi 
 BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET NEW.hour = HOUR(NEW.timeduration);
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

You'll likely also want a corresponding BEFORE UPDATE trigger, if you want to keep `hour` in sync when `timeduration` value is modified by UPDATE statement.